# How do I set up an application that holds files in IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I have a folder location that contains .txt files (say `C:\Files`). I need to be able to access it using `http://localhost/Files/myFile.txt`

I created a Virtual directory and mapped it to `C:\Files`. However, when I browse to the .`txt` file using the URL, it gives me an error. It appears that its looking for `web.config` file. I tried creating an application in IIS with the same result.

EDIT

[image]

Comment: What error is it giving you when you try to access it?

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Do I have to set it up as a ASP.NET website? Can't I just have files in the physical path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS 7 will always try to walk directories to look for additional config data (stored in web.config files).

You're throwing a 500.19 because the security context that your worker process is running under does not have rights to check if the web.config file exists in c:\files.

You need to grant NTFS permissions to your worker process to read from that location.

Depending on the version of windows and your worker process configuration granting Read/list folder contents to the IIS_IUSRS group is probably what you need.

Feel free to reply back with your windows/IIS version and the security context that your worker process is running under (Application Pools -> Identity) if the above suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: After adding IIS_IUSRS rights, I get HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized error. I am on Win Vista/IIS7 and this is my dev machine. I will need to get it to work on Windows Server 2008/IIS7

Comment: What is the security context that your worker process is running under? (Application Pools -> Identity column).

What authentication methods are enabled for the Virtual Directory? (expand the site -> click the virtual directory on the left pane -> select the Authentication icon under the IIS heading)

Comment: NetworkService is the security context. Anonymous Auth enabled.

Comment: For what it's worth - this is currently a Virtual Dir (and not an application)

Comment: A virtual directory is fine if you're just trying to display static content.

A screenshot of the detail of your exact 401.3 error and the permissions window of the c:\files\ folder would be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that the permissions were not propagated down the entire directory tree?  As a quick test can you throw a testfile.txt in the root of your c:\files virtual directory and ensure that the IIS_IUSRS group has read on that file, then try to get IIS to serve that test file via http://localhost/files/testfile.txt

Comment: No luck. I added c:\files\test.txt and browsed by http://localhost/files/test.txt - Same error. Should I be adding ASPNET user account to the files folder?

Comment: Can you list what groups/users have rights on your test.txt?

Comment: Nevermind.  I just looked more closely at your screenshot.  You're building out of c:\users\x\files rather than c:\files.  Which has different default perms.  I was finally able to repro your issue.  Open IIS mgr, select the virtual directory on the left pane, select authentication on the right.  Right click anonymous -> edit.  Select the application pool identity radio.  Refresh in IE.

Comment: SYSTEM - Full rights, Administrators - Full rights, IIS_USRS - Read & Execute, Read

Comment: Wow, that worked. Do you mind explaining what I did? :)

Comment: Basically the rights IIS uses to read files for display vs. the rights it uses to read the config file are different.  When I read the question initially, I thought it would be reading out of c:\files which inherits pretty loose permissions.  The permissions inherited from a c:\users\ subfolder are much more locked down and do not include the IUSR user (default user IIS uses to read anon content in vista).  You could have either granted rights to the IUSR user as well, or configured IIS to use the WP credentials to read it (which we did).

Comment: If/when you build this out on the server side, build out of c:\inetpub\something and all the permissions with automagically be built out right by default.

Comment: Excellent answer. Wish I could upvote more than once. Thanks!